# Angular 2 (Angular-cli) : Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-google-maps

I have been struggling for a couple of hours trying to make work **googlemaps** `PlaceResult` in my Angular 2 project that uses `Angular-cli`.

I had to install `googlemaps` using @types and add it under the attribute `"types"` of my `tsconfig.json` configuration file.

```
{
    ...
    "types": [
      "google-maps"
    ]
  }
}
```

And I succeed to use `google.maps.places.PlaceResult` in my Angular 2 Component by simply importing it !

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";
import { MapsAPILoader } from "angular2-google-maps/core";

import PlaceResult = google.maps.places.PlaceResult;
import GeocoderRequest = google.maps.GeocoderRequest;
...
```

Several hours later, I had to work with `google.maps.Marker`, which is in the same definition file as `PlaceResult` and `GeocoderRequest`. So I simply imported it as below :

```
[Line 12] import PlaceResult = google.maps.places.PlaceResult;
[Line 13] import GeocoderRequest = google.maps.GeocoderRequest;
[Line 14] import Marker = google.maps.Marker;
[Line 15] import LatLng = google.maps.LatLng;
...
```

But I had an unexpected error at runtime saying

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined    search.component.ts:14
at Object.444 (search.component.ts:14)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 26c2b97…:52)
at Object.727 (app.config.ts:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 26c2b97…:52)
at Object.602 (src async:7)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 26c2b97…:52)
at Object.1258 (.*$:7)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 26c2b97…:52)
at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 26c2b97…:23)
at main.bundle.js:1
```

Please note that webpack throws this error at **line 14** of my component. Meaning that (and correct me if I'm wrong) the previous lines (that uses the same "google") worked well.

Am'I missing something ?

---

I use :

- Angular : **2.4**
- Angular-CLI : **1.0.0-beta.24**
- typescript : **2.0.10**
- angular2-google-maps: **0.17.0**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update

Regarding import `LatLngBounds = google.maps.LatLngBounds;` I find out that I was calling the custructor (`new LatLngBounds()`) before the init of Maps api. In fact, I'm using `@agm/core;`. And constructor has to be called after `load()` as below

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {

                    this.page$.subscribe(page => {
                        if (page && page.content) {
                            this.latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                            page.content.forEach(w => this.latLngBounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)));
                        }
                    });

                }
            );
}
```

and I added in my typings.d.ts the following import

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

### Original answer

I solved my problem by having the following config :

1- **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "googlemaps": "^1.12.0",
    ...
  }
```

2- **tsconfig.json**

```
"types": [
      ...
      "googlemaps"
    ]
```

3- And add the google api script in my **index.html**

```
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
   <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places&language=fr" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

4- In components, use it like below

```
declare var google: any;

@Component({
    ...
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    // Google Maps
    bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds;
    markers: google.maps.Marker[];
    infoWindow: google.maps.InfoWindow;

}
```

Comment: Using @agm/core they suggest of putting your api key in the NgModule, rather than in index.html. Check [this](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/).

Comment: In my case, I had to put both my `@NgModule` and my `index.html`, after that, I no longer had the `google is not defined` error message